# “Quelque soit le repas”: Is this a valid structure?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, conjonctions

> Donc **quelque soit le repas** qu’on vous offre, il faut penser à dire gochisôsama.

I occasionally see native French speakers use the construction above, and I have always wondered if it is grammatically legitimate. I myself would use either of the following two forms:

> Donc **quel que soit le repas** qu’on vous offre, il faut penser à dire gochisôsama.
>
> Donc **quelque repas** qu’on vous offre, il faut penser à dire gochisôsama.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspected, *<s>**quelque soit**</s>* is incorrect. ***Quelque*** can't be followed by a verb.

Références:

[Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#71_strong-em-quelque-quelque-que-quel-que-em-strong)

> **Quelque, quelque…que, quel que** (sommaire)
>   ...
>   1. **Quelque**, en un seul mot, peut être employé comme adjectif indéfini (comme tel, il s’accorde en nombre avec le nom auquel il se rapporte)
>   ...
>   2. **Quelque**, en un seul mot, peut être employé comme adverbe (comme tel, il est invariable) :
>   ...
>   3. **Quel que**, en deux mots, est une locution conjonctive formée de l’adjectif indéfini variable *quel* et de la conjonction *que*. Suivie d’un verbe attributif (presque toujours du verbe *être*), elle introduit une subordonnée concessive au subjonctif

[Écrire juste](http://ecrirejuste.fr/quelque-soit-quel-que-soit/)

> Une erreur très répandue en français est d’écrire **quelque soit** au lieu de **quel que soit**.
>   En effet, il s’agit bien d’un regroupement de deux mots distincts : un adjectif indéfini **quel** et une conjonction de coordination **que**.

Comment: Hi. Je constate les emplois de « quelque soit » trop souvent pour que je puisse les mettre sur le compte de simples fautes de frappe.

Comment: Il s'agit rarement de fautes de frappe mais plutôt d'une faute de syntaxe courante.